# How to add below security headers in .htaccess WordPress

Tags: mongodb, wordpress, .htaccess, security, http-headers

My security test suggest to do below. But When I add security headers it's taking me to the 500 error page. Could somebody help me with these. Either way is fine.

[image]

I added the code top of the `.htaccess` file. What I tried was:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

<IfModule headers_module>
        RequestHeader set X-HTTPS 1
        Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade"
</IfModule> 

Header set Content-Security-Policy default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think when you are trying to add Referrer-Policy you should use mod_headers.c insted of headers_module

Comment: And with a http status 500 you _always_ should check what is in your http server's error log file _first thing_ ...